# EditText recebendo Null como valor, mesmo que esteja passando uma String com valor nela

Tags: edittext

Estou realizando a consulta no MySQL e verificando, IF MYSQL =! null, popula alguns campos do tipo EditText. Porém, não esta sendo possivel, pois esta dando erro que estou passando um valor null.

Como podem ver abaixo em meu código, na minha classe produtos + resultado do banco estão ok, mas mesmo assim não consigo colocar os valores para os campos EditText.

Pelas pesquisas que fiz, acredito ser via SetText que faço isso mesmo...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]